# How override singleTask using Intent flags Android

Tags: android

I have an activity (A) that is declared in AndroidManifest.xml:

> ```
>    <activity
>       android:name="A"
>       android:launchMode="singleTask">
>   </activity>
> ```

I want to from other activity in application start A and override **android:launchMode="singleTask"** to **android:launchMode="singleTop"**

How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to finish the current activity and post start activity to the activity ui thread.

```
// get rid of this activity instance and start a new instance one
finish();
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

See FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to start that `Activity` in an existing task, then you need to change the `launchMode` back to `standard` or `singleTop`. If you set the `launchMode` to `singleTask` then you are telling Android that you do not want your `Activity` to be launched into an existing task. Being able to override that would be counter-productive. That's the whole point of this `launchMode`!